# PHP Regular expression match multiple keywords Where last keyword is optional

Tags: php, regex

I have following text and i need to find part of text after specific keyword

```
Apple is tasty fruit
    orange is cool
mango is used to make shakes
        banana is a healthy food
```

Here is my regular expression

```
/apple(.*)orange(.*)mango(.*)banana(.*)/is
```

Here is the output

```
array(
    0   =>  array(0 => Apple is tasty fruit orange is cool mango is used to make shakes banana is a healthy food)
    1   =>  array(0 => is tasty fruit)
    2   =>  array(0 => is cool)
    3   =>  array(0 => is used to make shakes)
    4   =>  array(0 => is a healthy food)
)
```

it works perfectly fine if all the keywords are in the string
apple, orange, mango, and banana. However I want a regular expression that still work if last keyword `banana` is not provided.

```
Apple is tasty fruit
    orange is cool
mango is used to make shakes

array(
        0   =>  array(0 => Apple is tasty fruit orange is cool mango is used to make shakes)
        1   =>  array(0 => is tasty fruit)
        2   =>  array(0 => is cool)
        3   =>  array(0 => is used to make shakes)
    )
```

Comment: Make that optional: `(?:banana(.*))?` -- so only the `banana` part can be left off?

Comment: yes banana part is optional. Adding this works if banana part is missing if its there then its made part of mango. So it should work for both with or without banana.

Comment: Try making the matches reluctant, i.e. `(.*?)` instead of `.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

Use the `?` quantifier to let bandana be "optional" along with an OR to specify the end

```
apple(.*?)orange(.*?)mango(.*?)(?:banana(.*)|$)
```

I've made everything with lazy matching so it can work. Because of this, we need to add some new things:

```
(?:            Starts non-capture group
   banana(.*)  Selects "banana" and the text after it
|              OR (if there is no banana)
   $           matches end.
)
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV4iC3/1)

---

## Method 2

```
apple(.*?)orange(.*?)mango(.*?)(?:banana(.*))?$
Makes "banana" optional
```

This uses `(?:)?` to make the "banana" part optional. The `$` is needed as an anchor to know where the regex ends. This can be used to make many parts optional without much work:

```
apple(.*?)(?:orange(.*?))?mango(.*?)(?:banana(.*))?$ 
Makes "banana and orange" optional
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV4iC3/2)

## Method 3

This will require everything below it to exist:

```
apple(.*?)(?:orange(.*?)(?:mango(.*?)(?:banana(.*)|$)|$)|$)|$
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV4iC3/4)

This is a bit hard to explain so just checkout the demo and mess with one of the words (apple, orange, banana, mango)